# Identifying tagTech and reading a Tag using android nfc

Tags: android, nfc

My problem is i have to read a tag not sure what would be the tech technology for example it could be MiFare Classic , NfcV , MifareUltralight etc.
So I have to first detect the type of card and then read its UID based on its technology.
I can get the tag and also the tech list but then how do I determine where is UID would be in little endian or big endian
From the tag object I can create the TagTechnology object but how would i know which TagTechnology class i have to use.
I mean do I have to use
        IsoDep
        MifareClassic
So, I am missing a very basic thing but can't figure out what

To give an example , NFC Taginfo app does this and read any type of card.
Want to implement something similar but on a smaller scale limited to UID of the card only

Any help is appreciated

Thanks
Nirav

Answer (score 0):

The trick is rather simple: for example, `MifareClassic.get(tagObject)` will return `null` if that technology is not available on the tag.

Comment: Where can i find the information regarding the format of each tech supported  by android like in Mifare classic there is UID where as in NfcF there NCid2

Comment: For Android specific information you can lookup the API documentatio, e.g. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/MifareClassic.html For more low-level protocol information, I would recommend the "NFC Digital Protocol Technical Specification" available at http://www.nfc-forum.org/specs/spec_list/